# cannot import name 'parabolic' from 'parabolic'

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror

I am using Spyder with anaconda, firstly I tried to install it via anaconda but this didn't work so instead installed it via pip using:

```
pip install parabolic
```

however now when I try and call parabolic the following error occurs:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'parabolic' from 'parabolic' (/Users/harry/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/parabolic/__init__.py)
```

does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be. For context I am trying to run the following code:
https://gist.github.com/jgomezdans/434642/8b738ff4bff7f549f6255f5da3668f910b7352a2

Comment: That example code was last updated 11 years ago, so I'd expect it to only work with the Python versions and libraries that were available at the time. A lot has probably changed since Dec 21, 2009.

Comment: oh ok, doesn't look good then. Thanks anyway

Comment: To be clear, that doesn't mean it can't work. That was my suspicion for why it's not working; it may require a rather simple fix. I wanted to give you a good starting point for troubleshooting/trying alternatives.

Comment: Also from a second look, I can see that they didn't install some library called `parabolic`, they actually included the file in their project, which you can see if you scroll to the bottom of that link. You shouldn't have to install anything, just put all those `.py` files all into one folder and then try running it. Does that work?

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I thought I had to import the module as well as download the file. So when it was importing particle it was importing the module and not the file. Thank you very much all working now!